# Ubuntu firewall issue

Tags: dns, firewall, iptables, tor

I've broken my ubuntu's dns/firewall settings. I've installed toroxy and dnscrypt and after its deletion I don't have an internet connection even to my router.

```
ping 192.168.100.1 # router address
ping 1.1.1.1 # Cloudflare
```

returns

```
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

But after running

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT; iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT; iptables -F OUTPUT
```

ping starts working, but the browser returns a connection error. How can I reset all my dns(?) settings, or fix it?

Comment: We would need to see the entire firewall rules on your system.  SOMETHING is not playing nice, and we need to see what rules you have in place first - if they are interfering, then chances are your firewall is overly secured and overly restricted.

Comment: ufw has a reset option ... ufw reset that will go back to defaults.